# Transform javascript object's values to remove duplicates inside array

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object (of indefinite size) where the value is an array of strings. For example :

```
var obj =  {
    "article1": ["john locke", "sawyer", "john Locke"] ,
    "article2": ["person3", "person4"] 
}
```

I want to transform so that any duplicate string is removed.

That means for the example above, I'd have

```
var finalObj =  {
    "article1": ["john locke", "sawyer"], //"john Locke" was removed"
    "article2": ["person3", "person4"] 
}
```

It has to be case insensitive, i.e john Locke should be removed if there is already at the start 'john locke".

How to achieve this ?

Comment: well objects do not have a map, arrays do. So means you are trying to use map on the object, not the arrays in the object,

Comment: I know i edited my question: i'm a beginner : with array i'd know how to do using .map but here i  don't manage...tried some .reduce() but did not succeed

Comment: try `for (let k in obj){}`

Comment: so you need to change the case? since `"john locke" !== "john Locke"`

Comment: what is desired result for this `["john Locke", "john locke", "sawyer"]`, should the case of first occurrence of value to be maintained in output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first loop over the keys, than dedupe the arrays using a set. Since it seems case does not matter the array needs to be lowerCased before it is used in a set.

```js
var obj = {
  "article1": ["john locke", "sawyer", "john Locke"],
  "article2": ["person3", "person4"]
}

var finalObj = Object.entries(obj).reduce((o, [key, arr]) => {
  o[key] = [...new Set(arr.map(t => t.toLowerCase()))]
  return o
}, {})

console.log(finalObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for...in` and `reduce`

- Loop through object using `for ... in`
- For each key, loop through respective array,
- Change input value to lowercase and check if it is already in `includes` property or not, if it is not there than update `final` with current value and add that key into the `includes` property as `true`
- at the end return `final` and assign it to key of object

```js
let obj = {
  "article1": ["john locke", "sawyer", "john Locke"],
  "article2": ["person3", "person4"]
}

let removeDuplicate = (arr) => {
  let output = arr.reduce((op, inp) => {
    let key = inp.toLowerCase()
    if (!op.includes[key]) {
      op.final.push(inp)
      op.includes[key] = true
    }
    return op
  }, { includes: {}, final: [] })
  return output.final
}

for (let key in obj) {
  obj[key] = removeDuplicate(obj[key])
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Set()` but before that you need to take care of the insensitive cases, like `lock` `Lock`.

```js
const obj =  {
      "article1": ["john locke", "sawyer", "john Locke"],
      "article2": ["person3", "person4"] 
 };


 // this is for all the fields that are array ( will have unique elements )
 for(let key in obj){
  if(Array.isArray(obj[key])){
    obj[key] = obj[key].map(el => el.toLowerCase());
    obj[key] = [...new Set(obj[key])];
  }
 }
 
 console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code:

```
Object.keys(obj)
    .forEach(function (k) {
        var dict = {};
        obj[k].forEach(function (v, i) {
            v = v.toLowerCase(); // make value lower case since "john locke"!="john Locke"
            if (dict[v]) {
                obj[k].splice(i, 1);
            }
            dict[v] = true;
        });
    });
```

Note that this code modifies object `obj` and inner arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This will work -:

```js
let obj = {
    article1: ["john locke", "sawyer", "john Locke"], 
    article2: ["person3", "person4"] 
};

var finalObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  let uniqueArr = obj[key].map(i => i.toLowerCase()).filter((item, pos) =>            obj[key].indexOf(item.toLowerCase()) == pos); 
 return {...acc, [key]: uniqueArr};
}, {});

console.log(finalObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

For every attr in Obj:
  1. map the array to lowercase values
  2. filter duplicates

```js
var obj =  {
    "article1": ["john locke", "sawyer", "john Locke"],
    "article2": ["person3", "person4"] 
}

var newObj = {}

for(let attr in obj) {
    newObj[attr] = obj[attr].map(item => item.toLowerCase())
        .filter((item, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(item) === idx)
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for ... in, set, map and Array.from:

```js
var obj =  {
    "article1": ["john locke", "sawyer", "john Locke"] ,
    "article2": ["person3", "person4"] 
}
var newObj = {}
for (let k in obj){
    newObj[k] =  Array.from(new Set(obj[k].map((i) => i.toLowerCase())))
}

console.log(newObj)
```